# Mac - Max Texture Size for compatibility?

Tags: macos, opengl, size, textures

I have an OpenGL based game for the Mac.

Mac OS X 10.5 compatibility required, going back to pretty much any Mac that can reasonably handle Leopard, going back to G4 Powerbooks.

I'm building my sprite sheets/texture atlases, for feeding to OpenGL, and need to set a maximum texture size.

Q. What's the maximum texture size that a 5 year old Mac can reasonably accommodate?  Would I be safe making my sprite sheets 1024x1024?

Q2. Would all such hardware be able to handle non-power of two textures?

Cheers.

[edited]

I found the following (very useful!) resource:

http://homepage.mac.com/arekkusu/bugs/GLInfo_1058.html

From this list, supporting 10.5.8 as a minimum requirement, it would appear that everything I need the game to run on supports a maximum texture size of 2048x2048, which makes me very happy, as the use of larger sprite sheets negates the need for NPOT textures.

Comment: That table is also available from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1058.html